# How do I generate an instance of an array for multiple objects (of the same Entity type) in Core Data?

Tags: arrays, core-data, swift3, relationship

I'm very new to programming so hopefully I'm explaining this correctly, but some context: I currently have a `Restaurant` entity in Core Data, and the user is able to add new objects (restaurants like Sbarro, McDonalds, PizzaHut, ShakeShack, etc.). I also have an array of .csv preloaded menu items (using the `MenuItem` entity I made in Core Data) that includes things like french fries, pizza, hamburgers, chicken, etc.

What I have set up right now is a detail view that the user can navigate to from the list of restaurants. There's a 'menu' button that brings up my list of menu items, with a 'yes' or 'no' option that can be selected. This maps to a `Bool` property of `isAvailable` in the array of menu items.

At the moment, I'm able to save whether a restaurant has, say, lobster, but lobster also shows up as available when clicking any other restaurant (obviously an issue since McDonalds doesn't serve lobster) since I'm changing the `Bool` in the main array of menu items.

My question is: **How do I generate an instance of my menu items array for each individual restaurant so that the menu items' `isAvailable` status can be saved?** In the most ideal scenario each individual restaurant's menu items array would update if I made changes to the main one, but that sounds too good to be true. I've tried setting up a many-to-many relationship between my `Restaurant` and `MenuItem` entities in Core Data, but I can't figure out how to access the menu items through my restaurant objects.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to do this is to get rid of the `isAvailable` property and instead use the many-to-many relationship to track which restaurant has which menu items. You don't create a new `MenuItem` set for each `Restaurant`, you create one `MenuItem` of each type and relate each one only to whichever restaurants have the item.

For example given two `Restaurant` instances,

```
    myRestaurant1.name = "McDonald's"
    myRestaurant2.name = "Seafood Wonderland"
```

...and a `MenuItem` that only one of them offers,

```
    myMenuItem.name = "Lobster"
```

Add the menu item to only one restaurant's `menuItems` relationship. With Xcode 8 automatic class generation, this would be something like

```
    myRestaurant2.addToMenuItems(myMenuItem)
```

Use the relationship to look up each restaurant's menu items:

```
    let restaurant1MenuItems = myRestaurant1.menuItems
    let restaurant2MenuItems = myRestaurant2.menuItems
```

This gives you an `NSSet` of menu items. At this point, `myRestaurant1MenuItems` does not contain lobster, but `myRestaurant2MenuItems` does.

Comment: thank you for the response! That definitely would work, but the example I used in my OP was an (admittedly poor) attempt at obfuscating the true concept of my app that I'm building. If we pretend that generating an array of menu items for each restaurant is necessary (for the sake of discussion), is it possible to do so?

Comment: Yes, just create the instances. It's difficult to imagine a scenario where this would not be extremely bad design, though.

Comment: Duly noted on it potentially being extremely bad design! How would I go about generating an instance of the menu item array for each restaurant object? That's where I'm stuck.

Comment: You can create the instances anywhere that's convenient. I'd probably override `awakeFromInsert` in my managed object subclass and do it there.